Ubuntu Freezing every minute - after new install
I have a gaming laptop, I installed ubuntu 22.04 on it. Ever since i installed it, the computer freezes to an extreme and the mouse only registers every minute. Almost like it is 1 frame for minute. I bought a new ssd and even bought new usb flash drives to reinstall it on there. I don't know whats wrong with ubuntu now. I am at wit's end with this distro
Would also like to add that whenever I start the laptop with the "try ubuntu" the distro works fine, it's only when i fully install ubuntu into the system that it start lagging like crazy. My gaming laptop went from powerful to potato

Did you install the graphics drivers for your potato computer? If so, how did you install therm?

How much RAM and swap do you have? The terminal command free will tell. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.
